# Can I continue to use Aginity Workbench for redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, workbench, aginity

Aginity announced they are stopping free aginity workbench and moving to aginity pro and aginity team. Can i continue to use my aginity workbench which is free?

Comment: Yes it seems to work OK for me. Free is MUCH better than pro for redshift in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use Aginity Workbench for Redshift, but you'll be unable to get any support or new licenses.

Comment: Any references to support your claim?